# Removing a listview item from a listview item button

Tags: c#, android, listview, button, xamarin.android

I have implemented a custom BaseAdapter which displays list items with a custom layout.

Everything works but I have tried to add a Remove button to appear next to the items (which I have), however I am having issues trying to get it to work.

The relevant code is here:

```
    public List<OrderLineItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        OrderLineItem item = GetItemAtPosition(position);

        var view = (convertView ??
            Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomListItem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

        // ..........
        var removeButton = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnRemove) as Button;

        removeButton.Click += delegate
        {
            Items.RemoveAt(position);
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };

        // ...........

        return view;
    }
```

The problem is I think due to the delegate closure, because Items.Count is always equal to the offset of position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your analysis about the closure causing the problem is probably correct.

To solve this, I'd consider using the Tag field on the View in order to store the current item - then use that in the remove operation.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    OrderLineItem item = GetItemAtPosition(position);

    var view = convertView;

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomListItem, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

        var removeButton = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnRemove) as Button;

        removeButton.Click += (s, e) => {
            var originalView = (View)s;
            var originalItem = originalView.Tag as MvxJavaContainer<OrderLineItem>;
            Items.Remove(originalItem);
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        };
    }

    // ...........
    var tagButton = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnRemove) as Button;
    tagButton.Tag = new MvxJavaContainer<OrderLineItem>(item);

    return view;
}
```

Notes:

- It's important that the Click event handler is only set once - not set each and every time a View is used and reused.
- I decided to use Remove rather than RemoveAt because I felt it was easier to track in the case where item N gets removed (then N+1 becomes N, N+2 becomes N+1, etc). However, I think you could use RemoveAt fairly easily (I think the NotifyDataSetChanged call will reset all the displayed listview items)
- I've used this simple JavaContainer for the Tag field - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxJavaContainer.cs
- If you need to use Tag for other purposes then Android/MonoDroid allows you to store multiple tags using SetTag(key,obj)

Comment: Thanks Stuart. You might want to update your view.Tag = ... to set the tag on the button, as (s, e) => { s - is equal to the button as sender.

Comment: fixed. Thanks. You might also find at some point that the inline anon function can cause memory leaks - I'm still not sure I understand the intricacies of this!